# Migrate Java web project from netbeans to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, netbeans, migration

I have looked at some forums on how to migrate Netbean’s java project to eclipse. But I was looking for a way how to migrate Netbean’s java web project (I used JSF and Primefaces) to eclipse. Since the project is not that much big, I will also dedicate my time to do it manually. But, I have not sure on how to do that. Should I have to move just packages, classes, jar files and xml files manually? I don't have a knowledge in maven or scripting as well.

Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836647/migrating-from-netbeans-to-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your application to a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) application, that way you can have portability between any of the major IDEs.

If you haven't done anything odd with your build scripts then its as easy as copying and pasting into your new project.