# Importing Oracle's "PasswordStore" into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

So I'm starting to explore Java programming, and I feel I have a decent grasp of the basic syntax, conventions, and differences to C++.  In order to learn more about Swing, I'd like to dive into the PasswordStore source code provided on the Oracle website ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/overview/demo.html)).  I should mention that I am using the Eclipse IDE (Juno).

Unfortunately and embarrassingly, though, I cannot figure out how to import the project into Eclipse.  Most of the information I found through a Google search is telling me to use the "Create project from existing sources" option when creating a new project, but I cannot find that option in the New Java Project dialog box.  Using Import->General->Existing Projects Into Workspace results in a "No projects are found to import" message (I tried the main folder and all the subfolders except those within the `src` subfolder).

The folder provided contains a "File"-type file called `Makefile`, `manifest.mf`, and an XML document called `build`.  Digging around, I also discovered `genfiles.properties`, `project.properties`, `build-impl.xml`, `project.xml`, and a bunch of Java source files.  Immediate subfolders are `build`, `dist`, `nbproject` and `src`. I could just open the source files directly, but I'd like to do this properly.

Could somebody tell me what I am supposed to be doing here?

Comment: Also see [How to create a project from existing source in Eclipse and then find it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2636201/1048330)

Comment: Since the example you linked is a `NetBeans` project, you may also find [Migrating From NetBeans to Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/836647/1048330) useful.